# check number equality in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have numbers that will be coming from database with this format "+2349091736209" and I want to compare each number with a number I get from user contacts list. The value of phone numbers I get from the contacts is sometimes in this format "0909 173 6209" with spaces, while sometime like this "0909-173-6209". I need help on how to compare the db value with this variants and get if its a match. Thanks.

Comment: Search for "how to remove non-numeric characters from a string in JavaScript". I'm sure there are several hundred answers on Stack Overflow alone. Then add a plus sign to the start.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a good use for regex.

`dbNumber.replace(/\D/g, '') === contactsNumber.replace(/\D/g, '')`

This takes the string and replaces any non-number information with an empty string.  You can find this and more at one of the many Javascript regex playgrounds: https://regexlearn.com/cheatsheet

Answer (score 2):

phone_number.replace(/,/g, "");
phone_number.replace(/,/g, "-"); gives you the phone number without spaces or -. So you can compare.